# How to change text format 12- to -12 and to convert to numeric?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe where I have a column with the following structure:

```
Column1
12-
0
87
9708
987
607-
```

This is how the system output negative values, which is not in the right format. How can I take the - from the end in order to put in the beginning of the number and be able to convert to numeric type?

I though about regex or str replace, but I dont know how to say to take it from the end and put in the beginning...

Can you help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `str.replace` here along with `to_numeric`:

```py
df["Column1"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Column1"].str.replace(r'^(\d+)-$', r'-\1'), errors='coerce')
```

Note that the regex replacement used above would only fire for those inputs ending in a dash.  In those cases, the minus sign would be moved to the front, otherwise no replacement at all would happen.